# How build a 64 bit version of Ionic's ios@4.2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, 32bit-64bit

I have a problem, I had a problem with `ionic run -device` command, so I asked on StackOverflow, and they said that I had to use `ios@4.2.0` because the newest version of the ios platform had some problems with compilation. But, the problem is that `ios@4.2.0` doesn't nativly support the 64 bit, so I'm just asking if there is a way to compile it in 64 bit, to submit my app to the app store.